# How to display data in flatlist from API - React Native

Tags: react-native, fetch, render, flatlist

Im following this tutorial [tutorial link](https://www.knowledgefactory.net/2021/01/react-native-rest-api-calls-using-axios.html)

I'm attempting to fetch data from rapidAPI (using axios) and the JSON object array looks far more complex than than whats in the tutorial url

I cannot get the data to render in a flatlist

The code im using is below (coverted from turorial to my rapidApi axios request)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { FlatList, Text, View } from "react-native";
import axios from "axios";

function NotificationScreen() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  console.log(data);
  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3/fixtures",
    params: {
      league: "39",
      season: "2022",
      from: "2023-02-04",
      to: "2023-02-05",
    },
    headers: {
      "X-RapidAPI-Key": "mykey",
      "X-RapidAPI-Host": "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
    },
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .request(options)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
      })
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24, backgroundColor: "purple" }}>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
      ) : (
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: "column",
            justifyContent: "space-between",
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, color: "white", textAlign: "center" }}>
            Fetch content using Axios
          </Text>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, color: "white", textAlign: "center" }}>
            {data.title}
          </Text>
          <Text
            style={{
              fontSize: 14,
              color: "white",
              textAlign: "center",
              paddingBottom: 10,
            }}
          >
            Articles:
          </Text>
          <FlatList
            data={data.fixture}
            keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>{item.id}</Text>
            )}
          />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

export default NotificationScreen;
```

I think it is because the data returned are as objects (going by the console log below) and it possibly need to do something more complex to render the data in lets say the "fixture" array. The flatlist doesnt display if use the above code

The below console log shows the data is being successfully pulled but its the rendering i'm lost with. It works with the simple json in the tutorial

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sYbQ.png)

Disclaimer - I'm new to coding and react native in general so some of my terminology may be off

Comment: Please post the entire component and how you're fetching the data.

Comment: Hi Mr Vader - i have updated the details of the question to include the code im using and provided a little bit more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

From the data that has been returned from the API you just need to access the fixture attribute from the response as code below:

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
useEffect(()=>{
getData()
},[])
const getData=async()=>{
 await axios
      .request(options)
      .then(function (response) {
        // distruct the data object
      const {data} = response;
      setData(data.response.fixture)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
      })
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
}
```

Comment: Hi Salem - thanks very much for the explanation.


That has definitely changed the response from the API call where i can now see the items from the "fixture" array in the console log

However in my code above i cant get it to render the items in the flatlist (say id, referee, timezone..etc)

I've tried following guidance online but the best i can get it to do is output an number that not even in the results lol :)

Answer (score 0):

This code is written by @salem_raouf

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
useEffect(()=>{
getData()
},[])
const getData=async()=>{
 await axios
      .request(options)
      .then(function (response) {
        // distruct the data object
      const {data} = response;
      setData(data.response.fixture)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
      })
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
}
```

There seems to be an issue with the method you are using to retrieve the properties of each fixture array item. Let's confirm that each item contains the keys you are attempting to access.

Here, I change the FlatList component's renderItem function to match the real item structure within the fixture array.

```
<FlatList
  data={data.fixture}
  keyExtractor={({ id }) => id.toString()}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <View>
      <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>ID: {item.id}</Text>
    </View>
  )}
/>
```